# Read/View a Blob (PDF File) programmatically in Browser for an Authenticated AD User (Role Based Access Given to the Container level)

Tags: c#, rest, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My storage structure in azure portal is like:- *Subscription >> ResourceGroup >> Resource(i.e. a storage account) >> Many Containers >> Some blobs under each container*.
An **AD user has Reader access (IAM) to the storage account and a StorageBlobDataReader access to a Container named MyContainer. The Container's access level is private.**
Now he is able to see all the blobs inside that container and can view those too by clicking on them.

My Question is, if I get the Blob Url from the Blob property and paste it in a new tab just beside my azure portal's tab in chrome, why it shows : Resource Not Found?

My actual requirement is to open a pdf (i.e. a blob) in a new browser tab from the C# application if the application user is an authenticated AD user for that account/directory.

I guess the normal blob url should be opened to view the blob in the same browser window as that is already authenticated by the user when he logs into the azure portal. The Url should not require any SAS.

Sorry, As unable to load any picture to make my question more clear.

```
Actually am developing a Learning System, where AD autheticated users/Lerners will view some course material and when click on any of them, the related PDF file should be opened in the adjacent browser tab. The PDFs are kept in Storage blob. For this am not wanting to use SAS token. As the user itself is authenticated, so he should have access to all the courses (kind of Identity Management security).
So how to open that pdf in c#? I am able to provide RBAC access to the user by REST call already.
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a specific container permission, you can do this followings:

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources)

Comment: Thanks for your response.But my requirement is not exactly the same. I want to make my Container private. But without generating any SAS token for any blob an Authenticated AD user should view or open any blob file by its normal Url (https://videostoragelearn.blob.core.windows.net/test10/DLBook.pdf) in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it by implementing a SAS token which will be invalid after a short time but that will be still in use if the stream-channel is established between my application and blob container.